# How to create 2 dimension array of objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

I have these arrays:

```
appChartData: Array<{date: string, total: number, some_usage: number}> = [];
versionChartData: Array<{date: string, ver1sion: number, version2: number}> = [];
```

And I want to create two dimension array which contains the appChartData and versionChartData. 
Any help is greatly appreciated .
-k

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this

```
public mdArray = [10][2];

private addToArray(): void {
   mdArray[0][0] = appChartData1;
   mdArray[0][1] = versionChartData1;

   mdArray[1][0] = appChartData2;
   mdArray[1][1] = versionChartData2;

   //...
}
```

Of course you have to use loops 'n stuff if you want to add several pairs of these arrays.  e.g.

```
public mdArray = [numberOfPairs][2];

private addToArray(): void {
   for(int i=0; i<numberOfPairs; i++){
       mdArray[i][0] = getNextAppChartData();
       mdArray[i][1] = getNextVersionChartData();
   {
}
```